# Assets 2 thumbnails not showing in s3 sources sub directories

Tags: add-on, assets, thumbnails

The files show up but it just says "JPG" instead of showing the thumbnail.  The strange thing is that any images just in the root of the bucket show the thumbnail just fine but if i move that same image into a sub-directory I get nothing.

Seems to be pretty consistant throughout the site no matter what i do. I updated the indexes, tried uploading files directly to the bucket or through the interface, and i double checked permissions on both the local cache directory and the s3 bucket.

Related would it to filter a field to the sub-directory level instead of just the "source" level?  we use one master s3 account for all of our clients and would be nice to "bucket" their directories together.  I realize its a slippery slope with directories within directories but just one level would help us a lot..

Comment: Hey Keith - what version of Assets are you on right now? And of EE?  Also,w hen it says "JPG" - where is that? A template using assets tags? In the CP?  More details would help here a lot.

Comment: Hey Lisa, It's assets 2.02 and EE 2.5.5.  And everything I'm talking about is in the control panel, just in assets module screen.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're describing sounds pretty weird and I suggest you email us at support@pixelandtonic.com, so we can work with you individually to resolve this - most likely we'll bee needing FTP and Superadmin access to pull out all the stops on our debugging skills.

As for the other request you mentioned - am I understanding correctly that all your client resources are thrown together in a single bucket, only the subfolders differ? That by far is not the most optimal choice of managing files - I strongly suggest you use a different bucket for each client and thusly eliminate the problem. What you're asking for is a cure for the symptoms, not the problem :)

Comment: Hey Andris, I'll email support about the thumbnail issue.  As for the subfolder problem, I do want each client to have its own bucket but the problem is they all have needs for subfolders like "blogs" "programs" "artwork", which i know i can do.  The problem is that assets fields only let you limit file access to a "source" not a folder within that source, so if every client only has one source we cant really segment their images?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Keith, by the way Assets 2.1 allows to add subfolders of S3 buckets as sources, so you're able to implement this now :)